# No entiendo del todo esta función en Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy siguiendo una serie de tutoriales en Java y ahora estoy con las listas, en concreto con las listas en cola y hay un ejercicio que tiene algunas partes que no entiendo:

Un supermercado tiene tres cajas para la atención de los clientes.
Las cajeras tardan entre 7 y 11 minutos para la atención de cada cliente.
Los clientes llegan a la zona de cajas cada 2 ó 3 minutos. (Cuando el cliente llega, si todas las cajas tienen 6 personas, el cliente se marcha del supermercado)
Cuando el cliente llega a la zona de cajas elige la caja con una cola menor.

Realizar una simulación durante 8 horas y obtener la siguiente información:

- Cantidad de clientes atendidos por cada caja.
- Cantidad de clientes que se marcharon sin hacer compras.
- Tiempo promedio en cola.

  ```
  private void simulacion() {

  int estado1 = 0, estado2 = 0, estado3 = 0;
  int marchan = 0;
  int llegada = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * 2);
  int salida1 = -1, salida2 = -1, salida3 = -1;
  int cantAtendidas1 = 0, cantAtendidas2 = 0, cantAtendidas3 = 0;
  int tiempoEnCola = 0;
  int cantidadEnCola = 0;

  TipoCola cola1 = new TipoCola();
  TipoCola cola2 = new TipoCola();
  TipoCola cola3 = new TipoCola();

  for (int minuto = 0; minuto < 600; minuto++) {

      if (llegada == minuto) {

          if (estado1 == 0) {

              estado1 = 1;
              salida1 = minuto + 7 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);

          } else {

              if (estado2 == 0) {

                  estado2 = 1;
                  salida2 = minuto + 7 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);

              } else {

                  if (estado3 == 0) {

                      estado3 = 1;
                      salida3 = minuto + 7 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);

                  } else {

                      if (cola1.cantidad() == 6 && cola2.cantidad() == 6 && cola3.cantidad() == 6) {

                          marchan++;

                      } else {

                          if (cola1.cantidad() <= cola2.cantidad() && cola1.cantidad() <= cola3.cantidad()) {

                              cola1.insertar(minuto);

                          } else {

                              if (cola2.cantidad() <= cola3.cantidad()) {

                                  cola2.insertar(minuto);

                              } else {

                                  cola3.insertar(minuto);

                              }

                          }
                      }

                  }

              }

          }

          llegada = minuto + 2 + (int) (Math.random() * 2);

      }

      if (salida1 == minuto) {

          cantAtendidas1++;
          estado1 = 0;

          if (!cola1.isVacia()) {

              estado1 = 1;
              int m = cola1.extraer();
              salida1 = minuto + 7 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
              tiempoEnCola = tiempoEnCola + (minuto - m);
              cantidadEnCola++;

          }

      }

      if (salida2 == minuto) {

          cantAtendidas2++;
          estado2 = 0;

          if (!cola2.isVacia()) {

              estado2 = 1;
              int m = cola2.extraer();
              salida2 = minuto + 7 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
              tiempoEnCola = tiempoEnCola + (minuto - m);
              cantidadEnCola++;

          }

      }

      if (salida3 == minuto) {

          cantAtendidas3++;
          estado3 = 0;

          if (!cola3.isVacia()) {

              estado3 = 1;
              int m = cola3.extraer();
              salida3 = minuto + 7 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
              tiempoEnCola = tiempoEnCola + (minuto - m);
              cantidadEnCola++;

          }

      }
  }

  l1.setText("Clientes atendidos por caja: Caja1 = " + cantAtendidas1 + "  Caja 2 = " + cantAtendidas2
          + "  Caja 3 = " + cantAtendidas3);
  l2.setText("Se marchan sin hacer compras: " + marchan);
  if (cantidadEnCola > 0) {
      int tiempoPromedio = tiempoEnCola / cantidadEnCola;
      l3.setText("Tiempo promedio en cola: " + tiempoPromedio); }}
  ```

No logro entender varias cosas, pero en concreto: el primer `if` es cuando llega un cliente, su condición que dice `llegada == minuto` y la de cuando un cliente se marcha dice `salida1 == minuto` (por poner una de ellas), no sé porque se ha de usar esa condición, no le encuentro relación a los minutos del for con la llegada o salida. Supongo que es por algo que se me escapa de más arriba.

Comment: `llegada` es un `int` aleatorio generado más arriba que puede ser 2 o 3. `minuto` es una variable de bucle que va desde 0 hasta 660. Estás comparando que sean iguales para cada vuelta. Es decir que entrará en el `if` la tercera y cuarta vuelta de tu bucle, a no ser que modifiques alguna de las variables mencionadas.

Comment: Parece que tu pregunta se reduce a *No sé para qué sirve el doble símbolo de igual (`==`)*. Sería bueno para todo el mundo que en vez de pegarnos un muro de código nos pongas qué es lo que de verdad te da problemas un unas cuantas líneas.

Comment: He editado un poco y he añadido el enunciado del problema, a ver si ahora se entiende mejor lo que quiero preguntar con ese código y no me cosen más a negativos, que duele jajaja

Answer (score -2):

Arriba en la variable llegada `int llegada = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * 2);` se inicializa un valor entero de valor 2 + (un numero entre 1 y 2) * 2

Luego tu variable `minuto` se inicializa en el bucle for -> `for (int minuto = 0; minuto < 600; minuto++) {` Empieza con un 0, en cada iteración del bucle se incrementa en 1 hasta que minuto = 600 y se sale del bucle.

Por lo que en el `if (llegada == minuto)` se compara si las dos variable tienen el mismo valor. Si es correcto, se ejecutara el contenido de las llaves.

Comment: Eso si lo entiendo, pero no le veo sentido con el problema, osea que utilidad tiene que se tenga que igualar el minuto con el número de llegada?

Comment: Yo he respondido lo que creía que era la duda de que era el `if`, ya dudas de por que hace esto el código, poco te van a responder aquí. Igualmente, ya que estoy, te digo que el código es un sin sentido. Usa un sistema de flags (`estado1`, `estado2`, `estado3`) que se activan cuando se entra dentro del if que preguntas, pero que es un If que tal y como esta formulado, solo se entrara una vez, por lo que hay un montón de código muerto. Y ya si miramos despues del if, la segunda parte, todo es código muerto. No tiene sentido.

Comment: Código muerto = código que nunca se va a ejecutar

Comment: A ver, estoy preguntando esto por que como he dicho, estoy siguiendo una serie de tutoriales, seguramente más adelante habrá formas más óptimas de hacerlo, pero ahora mismo es lo que me enseñan.